# Overpass API Python wrapper (incomplete polygon error)

Tags: python, openstreetmap, query, overpass-api

I am trying to use the following query to get all buildings from the given area in OSM with the Overpass Api, but I am receiving an "Received corrupt data from Overpass (incomplete polygon)" Error. Where is the error in my query?

```
import overpass
api = overpass.API()

query = """
[out:json][timeout:25];
(way["building"](47.35436014253597,8.490386538763183,47.39245772996116,8.57950135269201);
relation["building"](47.35436014253597,8.490386538763183,47.39245772996116,8.57950135269201);
);
out body;
>;
out skel qt;
"""

response = api.get(query)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've also tried an approach with `requests`. The issue is not in the http call but when parsing the response. `overpass` does like `requests` (make http call) but also parses the content to use it directly. The parsing does not happen well. It could be a bug and you should open an issue at https://github.com/mvexel/overpass-api-python-wrapper/  as it seems GeoJSON support for relation in the library is not perfect e.g https://github.com/mvexel/overpass-api-python-wrapper/issues/48

I've taken another approach combining `requests` and another lib called `osmtogeojson` to do the same as `overpass` library

```py
import requests
from osmtogeojson import osmtogeojson

# Should use [out:json] in the query as later osmtogeojson does not parse XML
query = """
[out:json][timeout:25];
(way["building"](47.35436014253597,8.490386538763183,47.39245772996116,8.57950135269201);
relation["building"](47.35436014253597,8.490386538763183,47.39245772996116,8.57950135269201);
);
out body;
>;
out skel qt;
"""

url = "http://overpass-api.de/api/interpreter"
r = requests.get(url, params={'data': query})

result = osmtogeojson.process_osm_json(r.json())
```

Comment: thanks, I was aware of the requests solution but the combination with osmtogeojson is exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 0):

I tried running your query in [Overpass](https://overpass-turbo.eu/) and in Python (using `requests` instead of `overpass`) and it runs fine. Here is the code I used:

```py
import requests

query = """
[out:json][timeout:25];
(way["building"](47.35436014253597,8.490386538763183,47.39245772996116,8.57950135269201);
relation["building"](47.35436014253597,8.490386538763183,47.39245772996116,8.57950135269201);
);
out body;
>;
out skel qt;
"""

url = "http://overpass-api.de/api/interpreter"
r = requests.get(url, params={'data': query})

print(len(r.json()['elements']))
# 165715

print(r.json()['elements'][0])
# {'type': 'way', 'id': 4592724, 'nodes': [29039246, 29039249, 29033199, 29039253, 29039246], 'tags': {'addr:housenumber': '34', 'addr:street': 'Rotwandstrasse', 'building': 'yes'}}
```